# How can I get number of followers with Spotify in PHP?

Tags: php, spotify

I am trying to fetch the Spotify Artist Followers with the help of PHP. How can I get the number of Spotify Artist Followers?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Can we see your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Spotify Api](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/artists/get-artist/).

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{id}
```

This will return to you a bunch of properties, **including the number of followers**. There are a lot of included interesting fields.

You will need an authentication token from coinbase and add that to your headers.